# appcenter uitesting Invalid assembly path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

I am trying to get my UI Test uploaded to the AppCenter but I am getting this error related to Invalid assembly path.

> Is the assembly path the IPA iSO file?

```
C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\ReimbursementApp>appcenter test run uitest --app "NCCN/Reimbursement-iOS" --devices "NCCN/ios-12" --app-path C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\PathtoIPAFile.ipa  --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\PathToTheDebugFoler\
- Preparing tests... Invalid assembly path: C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\PathToTheDebugFoler" --artifacts-dir C:\Users\...\Local\Temp\appcenter-upload2019823-31556-xvhqh2.j3ize

Preparing tests... failed.
Error: Cannot prepare UI Test artifacts using command: C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\...\packages\Xamarin.UITest.3.0.3\tools\test-cloud.exe prepare "C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\PathtoIPAFile" --assembly-dir "C:\WebProjects\MobileApps\PathToTheDebugFoler" --artifacts-dir "C:\Users\...\Temp\appcenter-upload2019823-31556-xvhqh2.j3ize".
```